# Chai deep equal on objects containing functions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, chai

How to assert deep equal between functions in chai where their toString() representation are deep equal ?

```
expect(() => {}).to.deep.equal(() => {}); // => should be pass


const foo = (x) => {
  // foo
  return x;
}
const bar = (x) => {
  // bar
  return x;
}
expect(foo).to.deep.equal(bar); // => should be not pass because comment makes them different
```

Answer (score 0):

[Well you can't as author closed similar issue](https://github.com/chaijs/chai/issues/697)

> Deep equal is designed to compare deeply not loosely, if that makes
>   sense. In other words, it is designed to traverse the keys of an
>   object or array (and soon iterables) and compare the values of those
>   properties with each other. Importantly, when it gets to a value that
>   isn't an iterable, array, or object, it actually uses a
>   stricter-than-strict equality comparison (it uses SameValue).
>   Functions are not iterables, they have no keys which could make a good
>   quality comparison, and as such are given the SameValue treatment.